# Do you need a visa to visit Brest, Belarus from Poland as a Belgian national?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, belarus, belgian-citizens

My father is visiting Poland during summer. He wanted to visit Brest one day without sleepover, just in and out the same day (it's a border city, he told me). He has contacted the Belarus embassy but they haven't replied yet. Our local city council has assured him he needs only his passport to visit Brest but I fear they might be mistaken with the new rules for entry via Minsk.

Some googling has made me rather certain it is impossible to visit Brest while staying in Poland.

My parents are traveling on their own in a sort of road trip. He has no travel agent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of January 1st 2018 you can visit Brest and certain areas around it for 10 days visa free (77 countries). You can also visit areas around Grodno. http://www.belarus.by/en/press-center/press-release/visa-free-travel-time-up-to-ten-days-in-parts-of-brest-oblast-grodno-oblast-as-from-1-january_i_0000071906.html List of visa free countries http://mfa.gov.by/upload/17.01.11_list_states_eng.pdf

Comment: It is interesting if you copy the info from the website for you answer. It will help if there is any issue in the links.

Comment: NOTE: in order to benefit from this, you **must** book a visit at the national park of Brest or Grodno, and present relevant documentation at the border. Thus, pure city trips to Brest are **not** allowed. The Belarusian border agency made this clear to me via e-mail

Comment: Why not? You may buy a tour to Brest from an operator and visit the area, not necessarily the forest.

Comment: @AndreiBurdenkov The Belarusian border agency linked me this document https://bezvizy.npbp.by/en/?step=1

Comment: Choose Tour operators under Cabinet and get the list of the firms that will come up with the options to move around. Originally, National Park was the only provider of these tours and the park was the limit for 3 days. Now the area has expanded.

Answer (score 7):

You **do** need a visa to enter Belarus by land and visit Brest, and this has always been the case.

You can only enter visa-free at Minsk Airport or by land through the Belovezhskaya Pushcha National Park or the Augustów Canal, and you must then remain within these precincts, none of which include Brest.

Answer (score 2):

List from William's answer is visa-free scheme list for visitors from 80 countries entering Minsk Airport. 
Correct list for scheme of 77 countries citizens' visa-free-entering eastern borders is here: http://president.gov.by/uploads/documents/ukaz462.doc 
(you could put the text, which is in Russian, into Google Translate to see if your citizenship applies.)